# Communication of VB6 application outside client network with SQL server inside network

Tags: sql-server, vb6

Is there way to make the vb6 desktop application which is not on client network to communicate with sql server which is in the client premises?

Comment: How will your outside the network application be accessing the SQL Server machine? Will you have VPN access to connect to the SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

A far better option (a necessity if the app is for general distribution) is to use an intermediary service, either over web/HTTP or some other (possibly custom) protocol.

If you app is specific to your company/employer for their internal use, then you will need to use a VPN or similar to allow it to work as if it was on the same internal network.

Note that opening up a database server to the wider internet is asking for trouble and should be avoided at all costs.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to use port forwarding on border router to SQL server.

Better would be to encrypt traffic to/from SQL Server like this: [IPSec through NAT: Securing SQL Server remote connections](http://wqweto.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/securing-sql-server-using-ipsec-through-nat/)